# How to write a reverse loop for 2 conditions using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx

I have written the following function, which uses `openpyxl` and test values in `management_style` list vs. a column in a `.xlsx` called 'Management Style' (denoted by `min_col=3, max_col=3`). If the cell value =! of the 'Management Style' column cell of any value in `management_style`, the row is dropped using a sort of reverse loop and the indexes

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

management_style = [
    'Advisory',
    'Advisory - No Fee',
    'Holding',
    'JPAS',
    'Liquidity Management',
    'Trading'
]

model_type = [
    'Client',
    'Holding Account',
    'Holding Company',
    'Trust'
]


def row_cleansing(excel_file_path):

    workbook = load_workbook(excel_file_path)
    data_sheet = workbook.active
    
    delete_indexes = []
    for row in data_sheet.iter_rows(min_col=3, max_col=3, min_row=2, max_row=None):
        for cell in row:  
            if cell.value not in management_style:
                    print(cell.row, cell.value)
                    delete_indexes.append(cell.row)
                
    delete_indexes.reverse()
    for i in delete_indexes:
        data_sheet.delete_rows(i, amount=1)
    workbook.save(excel_file_path)

row_cleansing('data_to_be_split_test.xlsx')
```

You will note that the `model_type` list is not utilized in the code, which is where I need help -  how would I expand/refactor this function so that it tests values in both `management_style` (denoted by `min_col=3, max_col=3`) and `model_type` (will be `min_col=11, max_col=11`)?

In other words, I only want to remove rows if there is no match in the Management Style column vs. `management_style` AND in the Model Type Column vs. `model_type` list.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the row indices and get just the cells you need directly:

```python
    for r in range(2, data_sheet.max_row + 1):
        management_value = data_sheet.cell(row=r, column=3).value
        model_value = data_sheet.cell(row=r, column=11).value
        if management_value not in management_style and model_value not in model_type:
            print(r, management_value, model_value)
            delete_indexes.append(r)
```